# Wp Multi File Uploader not working

Tags: wordpress, multifile-uploader

Using WordPress plugin (wp-multi-file-uploader) to upload multiple files in my site. it is uploading the file when I submit the form it does not show up in post i am unable to get it in post.
what could be wrong?

Comment: Figured out what I did wrong. I had nested my <?php wp_multi_file_uploader(); ?> within a <div> within my form. The multi file upload just needs to be a direct child of the <form> element and it works!